# Android: Which adapterview and adapter to show a dynamic list of apps

Tags: android, android-layout, adapter, android-adapterview

For my thesis I'm trying to do a kind of market similar to the Android market. I did the db in mysql, now I'm thinking about the android client interface. I'm a beginner so i need your help.
I will have on my db a lot of app, I need to do a native app that call the db (there will be php in the middle) and show the list of the app as in the android market, so with a title, a icon, a rating and a cost. All this info are on the mysql db and I think that php will get me back to my phone a xml file with all the info I need.

This is what I suppose, but if for you should be different let me know. For example if the local SQLite should play a role in this (it will definitely have one to share metadata for apps I downloaded)

I read that for dynamic list of stuff it's better to use an adapterview that takes the elements of the list from an adapter, that is a kind of bridge with the datasource. But for example arrayadapter is based on textview only, other on imageviews only and so on...... instead my views are not so simple but are something complex with some images, some textviews, rating and so on.......

So I need to find the right adapterview and the right adapter.

Now for my purpose, for you:

1. Which adapterview should I use? I was thinking to use listview.
2. And the harder one, which adapter? Do I need to create a custom one extending the base adapter class or there are some adapters suitable for my purpose?
3. If textview is the base widget for arrayadapter, which one will be the base for mine? A complex widget so basically a viewgroup?

I read something about cursoradapter, but I don't know what is it and if it's what I'm looking for. If you know what google use for it's market, that would be useful :)

Explanations, examples or links are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a custom ListAdapter is what you're looking for. [Here's a decent introduction](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/).

Comment: Tnx usefull, but in my case the source of the data to read is the result of a dbquery......returning all apps available do you think that case fit anyway or it's better a cursoradapter so i can scroll all result rows?

Comment: Definitely a `CursorAdapter`. But you'll still use the concepts of a custom adapter to format it as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

you should take a look at aptoide and how it's build Hope it helped
http://www.aptoide.com